# Extra spaces added to classes name with Sublime Text 2

Tags: css, autocomplete, sublimetext2, emmet

I have a weird problem with Sublime Text 2.

When I write CSS classes, it add automatically a space who is associated to the class name and not interpret like a simple separator. This arrive after I put the bracket and press tab (shortcut for the autocompletion).

So when I write this class to my HTML, it didn't works because of the extra padding added (and I am looking for always for a long time, where the error came from, and it's only about this space added to the class name).

I create a jsfiddle and copy/paste little code from my sublime text 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/SB3KV/

```
<div class="myclass"></div>

.myclass {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

I use several extensions : Emmet, GitGutter, LESS, Package Control, SFTP, Sass, Theme Phoenix and PyV8 (automatically add with SFTP)

**Bad way**

[image: I write my classname]
(I press the key tab)

[image: I add the brackets and it's broken]
(the result)

**Good way**

[image: I write my classname]
(the correct behavior I want)

[image: the space isn't associated to the class name]

So how, can I fix this problem who give so many trouble ?

**Update 1**

Ok, it's seems to be the weirdest problem I have ever seen.

I make some search, but nothing interesting.

I deleted all my custom user preferences, nothing change, I remove all my packages, nothing change. I delete the ST2 application, no improvements, I also installed ST3 and I have the same strange issue.

It's the most boring problem I have encountered.

**NOTE**

When I inspect the class name element copy/paste from ST2 on jsfiddle or even in stackoverflow, there is a   non-breaking space. It's should be the problem, but I don't know at all, why it's adding this space after the class name.

**Big Update 2**

I think the problem didn't come from sublime text 2 only.

I tried to create a simple div on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wDrxn or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2SJUQ/ and it didn't work.

So, as you can see, there is a f*****k `&nbsp;` added between the end of the class name and the bracket. I have tried on 3 differents Mac, and I have the problem, on all of them. At this point, I can't figure out why I have this problem. They are all of 3 on Mavericks, can the problem come from this?

Comment: I have this problem with but with rare frequency, not always. Common plugins are Emmet, LESS, Package Control, SFTP, Theme Phoenix and PyV8 . But since you said you tried with no plugins and settings I don't think these are the problem. I have OS X Lion so if Mavericks is doing anything it is increasing the frequency. And I get this problem not only in css files but in php too (which is still rarely). And I didn't get the tab thingy. What the? You write class name, press tab and get brackets? I only get `:;`

Comment: Happy to don't be alone. ^^ Yep, I type my class name (with the dot at the beginning), I insert a space (CSS convention), add the opened bracket, press tab, and here is the magic : non-breaking space appear.